# How to call a method on a subclass passed as a paramter?

Tags: java, class

I'd like to call a specific method on a class given as a parameter like this:

> ```
> public static Entity selectEntityMenu(Class cl){
>     ArrayList<Entity> allEntities = cl.getAll();
> //...
> ```

All passed in classes (subclasses of Entity) implement the static getAll() method.
How can this be realized?

Comment: Use reflection. Look into the `Method` class. Or even better, refactor and use the command pattern.

Comment: Change the parameter type to `Class<? extends Entity>`

Comment: Maybe I'm doing sth. wrong but that does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reflection solution is as follows

```
Method getAll = cl.getDeclaredMethod("getAll");
ArrayList<Entity> allEntities = (ArrayList<Entity>) getAll.invoke(null);
```

Now this solution is extremely bad. For one, there's no guarantee that the class represented by the `Class` object will have the required method. Second, the `getAll()` method may return something other than an `ArrayList<Entity>`, possibly causing `ClassCastException` at run time.

A better Java 8 solution would be to define a functional interface

```
public interface GetAll<T> {
    public ArrayList<T> getThem();
}
```

and your method as

```
public static Entity selectEntityMenu(GetAll<Entity> cl){
    ArrayList<Entity> allEntities = cl.getThem();
//...
```

then invoke `selectEntityMenu` as

```
selectEntityMenu(SomeClass::getAll);
```

Now this isn't necessarily possible if you only have `Class` objects to work with, but consider refactoring options.

Comment: thanks a lot for your response! so does the functional interface only work with non class objects? i tried to get it working with classes but was not able to.

Comment: @0ax1 Th `SomeClass::getAll` is a method reference. You could also use a lambda expression. Those are explained [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html). Alternatively, you can create a subclass of `GetAll<Entity>` and pass an instance of it to the method.

Comment: alright, I'll have a closer look into all of this stuff. thanks for your time.